# SharpSVN commit multiple file so slow

Tags: .net, svn, sharpsvn

I am using SharpSVN to commit a Zend framework source to my GoogleCode host

But the progress of commit take too long time, about 1 hour while the source contain nearly 2400 files.

I tested with TortoiseSVN client but it seem no difference at all

Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: have you considered marking the answer below as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't take very long if you've made only a few changes. Modern source control systems will only submit the changed files, not the whole solution.

If you've actually changed 2400 files, you'll need to bite the bullet the first commit, then successive commits will be faster.

Comment: it mean i created a empty host,then i add zend framework to the working copy and commit all of them. But the time to wait for commit is really terrible

Comment: Well, that's a huge initial commit, probably many MB due to binary files. It's a one time thing, though. After that initial commit, following commits will be faster.